# Invertible elements $\mathbb{Z} / p^2 \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

Let $p$ be a prime. We are curious about the invertible elements of the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z} / p^2 \mathbb{Z}$. What we do know is that according to the Euler totient function there are $\phi (p^2)=p^2-p$ such elements. We want to determine precisely those elements $a*b= 1 \mod p^2$ or equivalently $\gcd(a,p^2)=1$. How would we determine such elements if all we know is that $p$ is a prime. Why is this important?

Comment: There is only one possible (nontrivial) common divisor something between $0$ and $p^2$ can have with $p^2$:  $p$.

Comment: They are just the $a$ with $p\nmid a$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think the person just doesn't understand why that hint completely explains things.

Comment: My question is, why do we consider the square of a PRIME. why not some number $n$, I  do not know how to use the fact that this  is a prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important $p$ is a prime because that way you know $gcd(a,p^2)$ might be only $1,p$ or $p^2$. It is clear the elements in the quotient ring which are divisible by $p$ are not invertible. So $0,p,2p,3p,...,(p-1)p$ are $p$ not invertible elements. So you have only $p^2-p$ elements left in the ring, hence all the other elements must be invertible.

Comment: Because if a number $x$ is a multiple of $p$ then $p$ is a common divisor of $x$ and $p^2$, so $gcd(x,p^2)$ can't be $1$.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I just realised after posting the question. Sometimes asking the question makes a thing in your head click :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\gcd(a,p^2)$ can have one of the three values $1,p,p^2$. Since $a <p^2$, so we can rule out $p^2$. So we just need to discard things which are multiples of $p$. So from all the $p^2$ elements we remove $0,p,2p,\ldots,(p-1)p$. The leftovers are all invertible.